# AutoHotKey How to save file as XPS without dialog box

Tags: autohotkey

At work I have to take "screen shot" of a 3rd party vendor website 300-400 times a day, and save it as a XPS or PDF file. I already build a program that will send keys to do Ctr+P, Select, Enter, Write File Name, Enter. But I am wondering if there are faster way?

What I have in mind is to execute this command automatically without the need of a Print dialog box, and physically enter the file name, and press enter to save the XPS files.

I am using Window 7 with Internet Explorer.

[image]

```
    Send, {CTRLDOWN}p{CTRLUP}
    Sleep, 1500

    Send, {ENTER}
    Sleep, 500
    Send, {ENTER}
    Sleep, 500

    PutWindowInFocus("Save")

    if (active) {
        Send, %cin% %dateOfService% Eligibility
        Sleep, 1000
    } else {
        Send, %cin% %dateOfService% Eligibility
        Sleep, 1000
    }

    Send, {ENTER}
    Sleep, 2000
```

Answer (score 1):

Combine [`Purrint's`](http://www.bcheck.net/apps/purrint.htm) `Print to default printer` option when hitting `printscreen` with [`PDF Creator's`](http://www.pdfforge.org/pdfcreator/download) `automatic-saving` feature and you have it reduced to a single keypress.  If the screen shots are done on a schedule, you can even configure `Purrint` to take the screenshot every X seconds, reducing it to zero keystrokes.